# How to put Javascript variable into JSON array response before outputting

Tags: javascript, json

Sorry, this might seem like a simple question but I am trying to put a javascript variable into a line of code from a JSON request.

Variable `var name = "BTC";` Although I am hoping to change this value from BTC to another variable that can be changed if I can get this to work.

```
document.getElementById("img").src = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com'+img2.Data.[HERE].ImageUrl;
```

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("img").src = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com'+img2.Data.+name+.ImageUrl;

document.getElementById("img").src = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com'+img2.Data.name.ImageUrl;

document.getElementById("img").src = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com'+img2.Data.[name].ImageUrl;

document.getElementById("img").src = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com'+img2.Data+name+ImageUrl;
```

and many more, although i can't get any of them to work. But when i put:

```
document.getElementById("img").src = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com'+img2.Data.BTC.ImageUrl;
```

it works. I have tried looking for hours on the internet unable to find the answer.

If it is any help the JSON file I am trying to access is:
https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/

(you may want to use a JSON parsing extension as it is hard to read)

Also my current code:

```
<script>

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   oReq.open("GET", "https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/");
   oReq.onload = function(){
      var img2 = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);
      renderHTML(img2);
      }
        oReq.send();

        function renderHTML(img2){
        var htmlString = "";
        var name = "BTC";
        document.getElementById("img").src = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com'+img2.Data.BTC.ImageUrl;

        }
 </script>

<img src="" id="img"></img>
```

Thanks, I would appreciate any answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close to solution, You are not using Bracket Notation correctly

```
img2.Data[name].ImageUrl
```

instead of

```
img2.Data.[name].ImageUrl
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked! I will be sure to make it the best answer when timer is up :)